# Include a table list view in details view

Tags: python, flask-admin

With `flask_sqlalchemy`, I have two tables (A & B) joined together by an association proxy table (C), in which there are some extras fields.

For now with flask_admin I have a `ModelView` on C, and in this list view I have appended (with the `column_formatters` option) a link on each item in the related A table column to its details_view page.

It works fine, but I don't know, in this details-view page, how to append a `filtered` table, based on C, with just the rows relevant to the selected A item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I answer to myself here if someone needs it.

I do the opposite by creating another list_view, but for the selected record I want by modifying the index_view method and passing extras params (details) to the template:

```
class TableCView(admin.ModelView):
    list_template = 'modified_listview.html'

    @expose('/')
    def index_view(self):
        self.a_id = request.args.get('id', None)
        self._template_args['a_id'] = self.a_id  # add more params here
        return super(TableCView, self).index_view()

    def get_query(self):
        # Filter records by a_id
        query = super(TableCView, self).get_query()
        if self.a_id:
            query = query.filter(self.model.a_id == self.a_id)
        return query

    def get_count_query(self):
        query = super(TableCView, self).get_count_query()
        if self.a_id:
            query = query.filter(self.model.a_id == self.a_id)
        return query
```